# Wordpress removing URL-encoding characters like %xx. How can I stop it from doing so?

Tags: wordpress, url, encoding

I'm creating a coupon site with wordpress using Deals theme from theme-junkie.

When I store URLs like this one below (note the %2C in within):

http://www.flipkart.com/laptops/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&offer=SelectLaptops_Upto15.&affid=vivekvivee&affExtParam1=blog

It stores as (without the %2C):

http://www.flipkart.com/laptops/pr?sid=6bob5g&offer=SelectLaptops_Upto15.&affid=vivekvivee&affExtParam1=blog

How can stop it from doing so? URLs like these are from my affilliate network so I was told that I HAVE to use them as provided so that I can refer customers and track sales successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where you store your url ???
in text editor or in custom fields ???

Comment: How do you get this custom fields to display ???
Put some code here or snapshot...